# Discord.js printing out ReferenceError: command is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm quite new to programming and i thought I'd mess around and try coding a discord bot using discord.js to mess with my friends.
Unfortunately though Im getting some errors, full log attached below (UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: command is not defined)

Here is the full code:

```
const BotName = "name"; // Name
const Token = "token"; // Token
const SpamMessage = "hello"; // Message
const YourDiscordID = 398561449078685717; // My discord ID 

// Actual bot code

const Discord = require("discord.js");
const prefix = "-";

const bot = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true});

bot.on("ready", async () => {
 bot.user.setActivity("Getting Things Ready", "https://twitch.tv/")

 console.log(`${BotName} Loaded!`);

 try {
     let link = await bot.generateInvite(["ADMINISTRATOR"]);
     console.log(link);
 } catch(e) {
     console.log(e);
 };
});

bot.on("message", async message => {
 if(message.author.bot) return;

 if(!command.startsWith(prefix)) return;

     if(command === `${prefix}spam`) {
         if(!message.author.id === YourDiscordID) return;
         let Ping = message.mentions.users.first();
         setInterval(function(){
             Ping.send(SpamMessage)
         },
             1200
         );
     };
});

bot.login(Token);
```

I expect to receive "Ready!" in the console after letting the bot join my server, instead its stuck on the message with a log in URL and if I type the command (-spam) on discord, I get the errors listed below.

[Full console log](https://pastebin.com/L4MUKajp)

Answer (score 0):

When your bot receives an event of type message, it invokes your callback and inside your callback you only receive `message`, so of course `command` will be undefined. Looking through some examples, I believe it should be like this:

```
const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/eslachance/3349734a98d30011bb202f47342601d3) is the full example, I suggest checking it out.

Comment: So while this did fix the issue, it brought upon a new one, unfortunately.
I pasted the code snippet you suggested just under my other constants (changing message to spamMessage).
The error I am receiving now is:

```const args = SpamMessage.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
                                 ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous>```

Comment: The error means your `SpamMessage.content` returns `undefined`, debug it to see what it returns. Before doing slicing and trying to do everything in one go, try to receive any message, then try sending a random message, and go on from there, go step by step, instead of jumping to deep water on your first swim, hope it helps!